# batch scripting getting arguments to handle argument plus one

Tags: batch-file, delayedvariableexpansion

I want to be able to get the next argument to compare to the current argument.  So when the argVec is equal to "--define", I want to echo the next argument.  I get the result "y" instead of "delivery".

My input is:
Cmd version version1 --define delivery

```
set inputArg=%*
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set Count=0
for %%x in (%inputArg%) do (
   set /A Count+=1
   set "argVec[!Count!]=%%~x"
)
for /L %%i in (1,1,%Count%) do echo %%i- !argVec[%%i]!
for /L %%x in (1,1,%Count%) do (
  set /A y=%%x+1
  @echo !y!
  @echo !argVec[%%x]!
  if "!argVec[%%x]!"=="--define" (
    @echo !argVec[!y!]!
  )
)
endlocal
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I added `@echo off` to the top of your script and ran it, I got the following output:

```
1- version1
2- --define
3- delivery
2
version1
3
--define
y
4
delivery
```

If I understand you correctly, the problem is the `y` on the third line from the bottom.

The reason you are getting `y` is because of `@echo !argVec[!y!]!`. This tokenizes as `@echo`, `!argVec[!`, `y`, `!]!`, which means "echo the contents of the `!argVec[!` variable, then echo `y`, then echo the contents of the `]` variable. Since you don't have an `!argVec[!` variable or a `]` variable, this reduces to "echo `y`".

To fix it, there is lots of good information at [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10167990/18356). For your purposes, the important part of that post is this:

> To get the value of an element when the index change inside FOR/IF enclose the element in double percents and precede the command with `call`.

Here is a version of your script that I think does what you want it to do:

```
@echo off
set inputArg=%*
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set Count=0
for %%x in (%inputArg%) do (
   set /A Count+=1
   set "argVec[!Count!]=%%~x"
)
for /L %%i in (1,1,%Count%) do echo %%i- !argVec[%%i]!
for /L %%x in (1,1,%Count%) do (
  set /A y=%%x+1
  @echo !y!
  @echo !argVec[%%x]!
  if "!argVec[%%x]!"=="--define" (
    @call echo %%argVec[!y!]%%
  )
)
endlocal
```

That prints:

```
1- version1
2- --define
3- delivery
2
version1
3
--define
delivery
4
delivery
```

I realize that echoing to the screen is probably not your final goal, so when you modify the script to do what you really want it to do, remember to use double percents around the whole "array", exclamation points around the index, and precede your command with `call`.

For example, if you want to add a compare condition, then set the contents of `argVec[y]` to a temporary variable from a `call`, and then use the temporary variable in your `if`, like this:

```
@echo off
set inputArg=%*
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set Count=0
for %%x in (%inputArg%) do (
   set /A Count+=1
   set "argVec[!Count!]=%%~x"
)
for /L %%i in (1,1,%Count%) do echo %%i- !argVec[%%i]!
for /L %%x in (1,1,%Count%) do (
  set /A y=%%x+1
  @echo !y!
  @echo !argVec[%%x]!
  @call set tmpvar=%%argVec[!y!]%%
  if "!tmpvar!"=="--define" (
    echo "found it"
  )
)
endlocal
```

Output of the latest:

```
1- version1
2- --define
3- delivery
2
version1
"found it"
3
--define
4
delivery
```

Comment: Thanks, but what if I want to add the compare condition
if "%%argVec[!y!]%%"=="delivery" echo true1

I'm not sure how to use the call on there.

Comment: @ThomasPham I edited the answer to include a case of comparing the value. It's easiest to set a temporary variable and then use the temp var in your comparison.

Answer (score 0):

You can not "nest" delayed expansions this way:

```
@echo !argVec[!y!]!
```

There are several ways to solve this problem, that are described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990); the most efficient one is this:

```
for %%y in (!y!) do @echo !argVec[%%y]!
```

**EDIT**: *Additional request stated in comment solved*.

You may use the same method to get the value of `argVec[!y!]` and use it in any way you wish. For example:

```
for %%y in (!y!) do if "!argVec[%%y]!"=="delivery" echo true1
```